# Как выйти из исполняемого кода в python?

Tags: python, cmd

написал простенького бота, только сейчас начинаю изучать Python, и когда бот стартует, я не могу никак закончить исполнение кода, кроме как закрыть консоль и открыть новую, чтобы заново начать исполнение кода взамен старому
Вопрос заключается в том, как мне закончить исполнение кода, чтобы каждый раз не перезаходить в консоль?

[image: Консоль с python]

Comment: `ctrl + c` нажать

Answer (score 0):

Если у тебя даже `Ctrl + C` не работает, попробуй добавить в бота команду, например, `/stop`. А когда бот будет получать это сообщение, вызывай `raise SystemExit`. Должно работать

Answer (score 0):

Бот для для какого мессенджера?

Допустим если ето дискорд то там есть специальная функция
`client.logout()`